# Dates in the same month of year?

Tags: php

I have 2 `DateTime` objects, and I want to check if they are within the same month of the year (eg. both are in March 1999). Is there a better way than this?

```
$d1->format('Y-n') == $d2->format('Y-n')
```

Comment: But you are using correct method

Comment: what "feels wrong" with your approach? It seems to be a pretty solid solution to me.

Comment: Are you looking for a mathematical solution? It may be slightly longer than the one you have now.

Comment: There is no way you can accomplish this with 'just' two integers (timestamps), so you'll need something interprets them. I am not sure if you even can get months and years as integers from DateTime, but I doubt it will make any difference if you compare two pairs of integers or compare 2 7-characters strings.

Comment: I feel wrong about comparing string representation of objects. I will feel better with comparing `getMonth()` and `getYear()` values of those objects, but according to [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), there are no such methods.

Answer (score 0):

first get month from the date

```
$date_format($date,"m");
```

and than compare both of them.
if you want you can also compare year using

```
date_format($date,"Y/m");
```

use difference function

```
date_diff($d1,$d2);
```

Comment: I think you meant date_format not $date_format on the first one